# How to count cases with the same ID but different variables in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a data set which has 4420 attendances to a medical department from 1120 people. Each person has a unique ID number and other columns are demographics and primary care provider. I want to filter the data so I can work out how many times each person attends the department and then analyse the data by demographics eg primary care provider or age. It shows whether each attendance is primary or duplicate but I can't figure out how to work out attendances per person.

Comment: you need to use `aggregate` command to count the occurrences of each ID.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to count the number of times each person has visited (assuming each one is represented by a single row in the data), use the AGGREGATE command breaking on the ID variable to add the number of instances to the file as a new variable. In the menus, Data>Aggregate, move the ID variable into the box for Break Variable(s), check the box for Number of cases under Aggregated Variables, change the default N_BREAK to another name if you want, and click OK. That will add a new variable to the data with the number of instances for each unique ID.